# Why does windows xp standalone group policy apply in the safe mode to the default administrator?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-xp

I am trying to turn standalone Windows XP installed on VirtualBox virtual machine into an AppStation-style machine (only one allowed application, taskbar, start with lone shutdown option, and a desktop icon of the app). There are two accounts - default administrator (with password) and user account.

All changes to the GP are done manually using the gpedit.msc snap-in. I have disabled everything I could think of (including cmd, mmc, regedit...) and allowed to run only the needed app.

It works as intended, but all those restrictions are also applied in any of the safe modes. So I am basically locked out of any configuration with usual means.

I have always thought that GP restrictions are not applied to the default administrator during the safe mode - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994620.aspx. Well at least when you are not in a domain - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555995.

My questions are:

- Is it correct behaviour or am I missing something?
- And if it is intended behaviour, then is there any standard way that could allow me to administer
  such a machine?

Comment: What i want to change some settings, allow some other app to run? I am unable do to it in the usual mode due to all those GP restriction. I have to do it in the safe mode. But those restrictions are nonetheless still applied to the administrator in the safe mode. And that is the problem.

Comment: Oh, I get it, now.  You need to change the local group policy settings.  Which you can do as an Administrator.  It's called Local Group Policy.  So... what's your problem?  Did you just not know about local group policy?

Comment: But I have locked myself from everything - cmd, mmc, regedit, WIn+R, Ctrl+Alt-Del... I thought that such restrictions do not apply to admin is the safe mode.

Comment: Regedit?  Starting to sound like the easier solution is to re-image the box... and not screw yourself up so bad next time.

Comment: I see it. But I want to know whether such behaviour is intended(and all those resources I've searched lie about the GP restrictions for admin in safe mode) or I'm just making something totally wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is intended behavior.

Comment: But here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994620.aspx (search for safe mode) is said otherwise.

Comment: But I see - Ctrl+F "Safe mode".

Comment: `Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Vista`  Doesn't apply to XP, which you're using.  And since it doesn't apply to XP, it doesn't apply to XP.

Comment: Nonetheless, thank you for your time(that's not an irony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is intended behavior.  [Group Policy applies regardless of network connectivity, and even in safe mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555995).  By design.

Comment: There is something controversial about those two statements(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994620.aspx. and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555995). And also I think(may be incorrectly) that GPO aren't actually created or managed on standalone non-AD machine.

Comment: @GeneMounty Yeah, read which OSes the *Technet* document applies to.  You're not using one of the OSes that document lists in the `Applies to:` section, so you shouldn't expect it to apply.

Comment: If there are won't be any more suggestions for some time I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: But [Group policy appl...](support.microsoft.com/kb/555995) does not list XP in APPLIES TO section. It lists only 2000 and 2003 server. Maybe that's a bit nitpickingly from me, but...

Comment: @GeneMounty Maybe.  The thing is, though, that XP and Server 2003 are built on the same architecture,  whereas the architecture changed radically between XP and Vista (or 7).  You could think of Windows XP as the client version of Windows 2003 Server (and vice-versa), but with all the core changes to the operating between XP and Vista, ... well, a lot of things are different, so it's a much less safe assumption that something that applies to XP would apply to Vista/7 (and vice-versa).